# Пригласительная ссылка в приватный канал создается уже просроченная (aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Создавала ссылку на chat с помощью

```
link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(TEST_ID, member_limit=1)
```

Все работало, пригласительная ссылка на одного человека создавалась.

Сейчас решила поменять TEST_ID с ID чата на ID приватного канала, ссылка создается, но при нажатии на нее появляется "срок действия ссылки истек", несмотря на то, что по ней никто не переходил

Также пробовала:

```
link = await bot.export_chat_invite_link(TEST_ID_CHENNEL)
```

но та же история

Может нужно установить какие-то настройки в самом канале?

Подскажите пожалуйста и заранее спасибо!

Comment: В методе create_chat_invite_link есть параметр expire_date, поробуйте указать любую дату.

Comment: @ProgerOffline разобралась, проблема была в том, что когда я тестировала удаление пользователя и приглашение его обратно, то не добавила его анбан, для чата анбан не нужен, для канала нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решила свой вопрос, может кому будет полезно:

Проблема заключалась в том, что я тестировала возможность по времени удалять пользователей и приглашать по ссылке обратно

Добавила пользователя, удалила, обратно не смогла пригласить, поскольку при удалении из канала пользователь **автоматически добавляется в черный список канала**, чтобы пригласить его повторно, нужно:

```
await bot.kick_chat_member(TEST_ID_CHENNEL, user_id)
await bot.unban_chat_member(TEST_ID_CHENNEL, user_id)
```